# How to fix the size of a clickable area in a shape with macro assigned - Excel

Tags: excel

I have a shape with a macro assigned to it. The problem is that the clickable area of this shape is way bigger than the shape itself and it span 2 rows. Is there a way to change the clickable area size so it is contained within the shape.
I noticed that this problem is affecting only the bottom side of the shape.

If there is no way to fix this issue, is there a better way to create a button in excel that is not as boring as the standard button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons are boring.

You can make a far better button using a `TextBox`.  Enter it like:

[image]

Then you can put text in the Shape and format the text.

Then right-click the Shape and select `Format Shape` at the bottom of the Context Menu.

You can add color to the shape and apply 3_D formatting.  An example:

[image]

You can assign a macro to the TextBox just like a Button.

Comment: That's right. Thank you for your reply. Assigning the macro to TextBox worked perfectly!.

Comment: @RodFar  You are welcome...........my favorite way to make a "button" is to start with a `TextBox`